# MOQ - verify exception was thrown

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I working with MOQ framework for my testing.
I have a scenario in which I expect a fault exception to be thrown.
How can I verify it was thrown?

```
public void Koko(List<string?> list) 
{ 
   foreach(string? str in list) 
   { 
        if (str != null) someProperty.Foo(str); 
        else throw new FormatException(); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 76):

If you want to verify an exception was thrown (by your own code) then Moq is not your tool of choice for that.
Simply use one of the unit test frameworks available.

**Xunit/NUnit:**

```
Assert.Throws<SomeException>(() => foo.Bar());
```

**Fluent Assertions:**

```
Action act = () => foo.Bar();
act.Should().Throw<SomeException>();
```

https://fluentassertions.com/introduction

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.6.2

Comment: If you're using the latest FluentAssertions package you would verify an exception was thrown like this:

Action action = () => foo.Bar();
action.Should().Throw<Exception>();

Comment: What if `Bar()` is an `async` method?

Comment: @Lukas
FluentAssertions has a nice support for this case
`Func<Task> act = () => foo.BarAsync();
await act.Should().ThrowAsync<SomeException>();`

Comment: Don't forget to mark the lambda function as asynchronous in that case (`... async () => ...`).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  AlanT's solution is the answer.

Answer (score 32):

I may be mis-reading your intent, but as far as I can see there is no need to do anything to a mock in order to test that the exception has been thrown.

It looks like you have a class with a method Foo that takes a string - lets call this InnerClass

```
public class InnerClass {
    public virtual void Foo(string str) {
         // do something with the string
    }
}
```

and a class which contains an InnerClass as a property (someProperty) which has a member Koko that takes a List<string> as a parameter

```
public class OuterClass {

    private readonly InnerClass someProperty;

    public OuterClass(InnerClass someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }

    public void Koko(List<string> list) {
         foreach (var str in list) {
              if (str != null)
                   someProperty.Foo(str);
              else
                   throw new FormatException();
          }
    } 
}
```

**NOTE:** I cannot get List<string?> to compile - tells me that the underlying type (string) must be non-nullable.  AFAIK, one only needs to make value types nullable, reference types are implicitly nullable.

It looks like you want to test that if you pass in a list of strings where any of them are null that a FormatException is thrown.

If so, then the only reason for a MOQ is to release us from worrying about the InnerClass functionality.  Foo is a method, so, unless we are using strict mocks, we can just create an InnerClass mock with no other setup.

There is an attribute [[ExpectedException]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) with which we can tag our test to verify that the exception has been thrown.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException))]
public void ExceptionThrown() {

    var list = new List<string>() {
        "Abel",
        "Baker",
        null,
        "Charlie"
    };

    var outer = new OuterClass(new Mock<InnerClass>().Object);
    outer.Koko(list);

}
```

This test will pass if a FormatException is thrown and fail if it is not.

Comment: I did not know about the ExpectedException Attribute, this is great! Thanks.

Comment: This is the real answer. Thanks

Comment: The downside of using the ExpectedException attribute is that you can't be specific about what action should cause the exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 17):

Reading through these answers I realized there is yet another way to do this using NUnit. The following gets the exception text from an exception and verifies the error message text.

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<SomeException>(() => foo.Bar());
Assert.That(ex.Message, Is.EqualTo("Expected exception text");
```

And I couldn't get the decoration / attribute syntax to work (AlanT's answer above) using the latest version of NUnit -- not sure why, but it complained no matter what I tried to do.

Answer (score 13):

Please read this [Introduction to Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart). Here is the way to setup `InvalidOperationException` throwing when `DoSomething` method is invoked:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething()).Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
```

Then simply verify if method was called. If it was called, then exception was raised

```
mock.Verify(foo => foo.DoSomething());
```

Comment: I don't want to setup an exception.
I want to verify it does get thrown.

Comment: @GZ you are trying to verify if Moq working? If you setup exception throwing it will be thrown if method was invoked. Simply verify if method was invoked.

Comment: I'll explain the scenario in more detail. Maybe my approach is incorrect.

I have a foreach loop running on two object. One is available and one is null.

I want to verify two things, first method run on available object and that an exception thrown for the null object (In method I check for null and if so throw the exception manually).

Comment: And what you are mocking here? It would be nice to see your code.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is forbidden to advertise code (work policy).

Comment: @GZ you don't need to paste exact code. Write similar code which describes your problem. From your description it's not clear what you are mocking and what you are verifying. Actually you were asking about verifying that Moq thrown exception - code above does that.

Comment: public void Koko(List<string?> list)
        {
            foreach(string? str in list)
            {
                if (str != null)
                    someProperty.Foo(str);
                else
                    throw new FormatException(); 
            }
    }



 I act on two strings, one is null and the other is not. I want to verify Foo runs once and FormatException is thrown.

Comment: @GZ I still don't see any mocks. BTW do you know that strings are nullable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28357/discussion-between-lazyberezovsky-and-g-z)

Answer (score 12):

You can test that an Exception is thrown using NUnit Asserts:

```
Assert.That(() => testObject.methodToTest(), Throws.TypeOf<FaultException>());
```

Answer (score 9):

An old question but no source code actually showing what the solution was, so here's what I did:

```
var correctExceptionThrown = false;

try
{
    _myClass.DoSomething(x);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message == "Expected message")
        correctExceptionThrown = true;
}                    

Assert.IsTrue(correctExceptionThrown);
```

Note rather than checking the message, you can catch a particular type of exception (generally preferable).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I solved it in the following way.

Since the exception broke my test I put the method call in the Because block in try-catch.

Then I could use a simple Verify.

Thanks to all helpers...

Comment: Consider posting your solution code, as others could learn from it or comment on it. You could also mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: sounds like AlanT had the right answer. In Moq if you want to test `Foo(string)` will throw `ArgumentException` you should be using `ExpectedException`