# Exception not thrown by mocked object

Tags: c#, exception, moq, throw

Objective is to unit test a PUBLIC VOID Method.

I have a mocked service, which my class-under-test would call, in a for-each loop with 3 different parameters.

The class-under-test passes some input parameters to "SendRequest" method of the service which executes using those parameters.

I want the mocked service to throw an exception when one of the parameters has a specific value e.g "abc".
I use something like this:

```
   public class ClassUnderTest
   {
       private IMyService _myservice;
       public ClassUnderTest(IMyService myservice)
       {
           _myservice = myservice;
       }
       public void MyMethod()
       {
           //assume I get those 3 values from somewhere, in here.
           var list = new List<string>{"abc","aaa","bbb"};
           foreach(var item in list)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       _myservice.SendRequest(item);
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                       //do some logging and continue calling service with next item in list
                   }
              }
       }
   }

        var myService = new Mock<IMyService>();
        myService.Setup(x => x.SendRequest("abc")).Throws<Exception>();
        myService.Setup(x => x.SendRequest("aaa"));
        myService.Setup(x => x.SendRequest("bbb"));

        var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(myService.Object);
        classUnderTest.MyMethod();
        myService.Verify(x =>x.SendRequest(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(2));
```

**More Context:**
As MyMethod returns void, to test it, I can only rely on the the fact that my dependencies were invoked at different portions of the code in this method. For e.g. if there is a null check for input parameters before service call, the method would return before it invokes the service. If it goes past null check, the dependency service would be invoked. I would be able to trace these in the code coverage results( and in debug mode).

When I run the test, it fails because its invoking the service thrice but I expect the invocation to happen twice(now may be I am wrong and may be that although it is supposed to throw exception the invocation attempt is still counted by Verify call and hence I get 3 runs).

Whatever be the case, on debug I see that the service never throws exception. I have a try-catch in the for-each-loop where I want to do some logging and continue calling the service again with the next value. But I never get to get inside the Catch block.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show your actual code

Comment: How do you make sure `classUnderTest.MyMethod()` will invoke `myService.SendRequest()` with "abc"? Did you debug and see?

Comment: Are you sure the correct type of exception is caught?

Comment: Well of course the verify fails - you're calling that method 3 times! Verifying the method call doesn't care about the outcome of the method. You'll need to verify some other measurement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MOQ - verify exception was thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053433/moq-verify-exception-was-thrown)

Comment: [1]  Even if exception is thrown, `SendRequest` will be called thrice.  [2] And the exception thrown by `MyService` doesn't matter here, because your `MyMethod` handles that. Un-handled exceptions behave differently in unit tests though.

Comment: I need to be able to test out the Catch block of MyMethod, where I would be having additional code to do some stuff. Assert.Throws<Exception>() just asserts whether that delegate when invoked will throw the specified exception. Not what I need. I need the exception to be thrown when unit test is calling the service, so that it also enters the Catch block of My Method.

Comment: @OwenPauling Yes the invocation count would still be 3 I guess.

Comment: It invokes it three times.  One of the times it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Specific Exception**
My 1st suggestion would throw a more specific exception so you can be more sure.

**Option 2: Inject an ILogger service**
Refactor out the logging into an ILogger and inject that in. Then pass a mock of that in and assert against it.

**Option 3: Extract and Override**
If you must check catch block was hit you can use extract and override:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private IMyService _myservice;
    public ClassUnderTest(IMyService myservice)
    {
        _myservice = myservice;
    }
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //assume I get those 3 values from somewhere, in here.
        var list = new List<string>{"abc","aaa","bbb"};
        foreach(var item in list)
            {
                try
                {
                    _myservice.SendRequest(item);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    LogError(ex);
                }
            }
    }

    protected virtual LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        //do logging
    }
}

public class TestableClassUnderTest : ClassUnderTest
{
    public bool LoggingWasCalled { get; set; }

    protected virtual LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        LoggingWasCalled = true;
    }
}
```

Then you could sheck something like this:

```
var testableSut = new TestableClassUnderTest ();
testableSut.MyMethod("abc");
Assert.True(testableSut.LoggingWasCalled);
```

I walk through it in more detail here: http://devonburriss.me/testing-the-untestable/