# MSTest ThrowsException with conditions on the exception object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, mstest, assert

I'm using MSTest `Assert.ThrowsException`, but sometimes I want to add test conditions on the thrown exception object, e.g. checking that the message mentions a specific phrase, identifier, data value or whatever.

The best solution I've found is a construct that doesn't use `Assert.ThrowsException`, but resorts to `try...catch`:

```
bool success = false;
try
{
    // Code to be tested goes here...
    success = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(e, typeof(DesiredExceptionClass));
    // Tests on e go here...
}
if (success)
    Assert.Fail($"Should have thrown {nameof(DesiredExceptionClass)}.");
```

Is there a better way?

With "better" i mean more readable, compacter code, with less "boilerplate".

Comment: I am aware of other testing frameworks as well as e.g. FluentAssertions, but I'm asking for solutions with out-of-the-box MSTest.

Comment: What about this style `Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(() => myClass.MyMethodWithError());` than you can access _Exception_ object and check its data

Comment: There is also an article http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/01/asserting-exceptions-in-mstest-with.html

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I don't understand how/where I will be able to access the exception object. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this way:

```
    Exception exception = null;
        try
        {
            // Code to be tested goes here...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(exception, typeof(DesiredExceptionClass));
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [pattern I have post in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317832/4332059) to verify additional expectations when an exception should be raise.

It seems like you are trying to reduce the "Boilerplate Code" so i have created the following helper class:

```
public static class ExceptionAssert
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this method if your UT is using <see cref="ExpectedExceptionAttribute"/> and you want to verify additional expectations
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The expected exception type base</typeparam>
    /// <param name="action">Execute the unit to test</param>
    /// <param name="verifier">Verify the additional expectations</param>
    public static void AssertException<T>(Action action, Action<T> verifier) where T: Exception
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch(T e)
        {
            verifier(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this method if your UT is not using <see cref="ExpectedExceptionAttribute"/> and you want to verify additional expectations
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The expected exception type base</typeparam>
    /// <param name="action">Execute the unit to test</param>
    /// <param name="verifier">Verify the additional expectations</param>
    /// <param name="allowDriven">Indicates if the raised exception can be an instance of driven class</param>
    public static void AssertExceptionWithoutExcepctedExceptionAttribute<T>(Action action, Action<T> verifier, bool allowDriven = true) where T : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            Assert.Fail("No Exception raised");
        }
        catch (T e)
        {
            if (!allowDriven && e.GetType() != typeof(T))
            {
                Assert.Fail($"The raised exception :: {e.GetType()} is a driven instance of :: {typeof(T)}");
            }
            verifier(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can execute your UT as one of the following:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), AllowDerivedTypes = true)] // change the attribute settings
public void Foo()
{
    // do arrange:

    ExceptionAssert.AssertException<Exception>(() => // change "Exception" to the required exception type or left it as any exception
    {
        // do the act:

    }, exception =>
     {
         // do you asserts statements:
     });
}

[TestMethod]
public void FooBar()
{
    // do arrange:

    ExceptionAssert.AssertExceptionWithoutExcepctedExceptionAttribute<Exception>(() => // change "Exception" to the required exception type or left it as any exception
    {
        // do the act:

    }, exception =>
    {
        // do you asserts statements:
    }, false);
}
```

BTW, IMO you should never verify the exception itself except his type/driven(or if it is a custom exception with additional information) since your code should never depends on his MSG, call-stack and etc... I think that this is the reason why MS didn't add to  [ExpectedExceptionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=mstest-net-1.2.0) the ability to verify the MSG.